# Facebook login api with Django allauth

Tags: python, facebook-login, django-allauth, django-2.0

Im trying to connect Facebook login api to my project, using `Django allauth`. Although it seems that something is not working...

When I run my project on `localhost`, it shows:

> `"Page not found - Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/accounts/facebook/login/token/login.html"`

And also say that this path (`accounts/Facebook/login/token/login.html`) does not match with anything.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the SO. Would you please translate your question to English ?

Comment: Hey!! Of course

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention your username... @Yasen

Answer (score 0):

There is detailed explanation howto add your app with `django-allauth` to the Facebook.

See [Django-allauth Facebook Login](https://medium.com/@jinkwon711/django-allauth-facebook-login-b536444cbc6b) by Kwon Jinhwan

According to your error report, author recommends this:

> Add this code to your urlpatterens
>
> `url(r'^accounts/',include('allauth.urls')),`

Also, there is working example, you might try it

[sushaantu/django-allauth-example: Working example of django-allauth](https://github.com/sushaantu/django-allauth-example)